# Hide 'previous' on first and 'next' on last image in views slideshow

Tags: views

I create slideshow using Views Slideshow module, controls are enabled (previous, next), I enable and 'End slideshow after last slide' in settings.

Now, how I can hide 'previous' text on first image in slide and 'next' text on the last image in slide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve problem using jQuery, there is code that I use in my case:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

function Left() {
    if ($('#views_slideshow_cycle_div_slide-block_1_0').css('display') == 'block') {
    $("#views_slideshow_controls_text_previous_slide-block_1").css({"visibility": "hidden"});
}
else {
$("#views_slideshow_controls_text_previous_slide-block_1").css({"visibility": "visible"});
}
};

function Right() {
    if ($('#views_slideshow_cycle_div_slide-block_1_2').css('display') == 'block') {
    $("#views_slideshow_controls_text_next_slide-block_1").css({"visibility": "hidden"});
}
else {
$("#views_slideshow_controls_text_next_slide-block_1").css({"visibility": "visible"});
}
};

window.setInterval(function(){
    Left();
    Right();
}, 10);

});
```

Because 'previous' is visible until page is fully loaded and then disappear, I add to css:

```
#views_slideshow_controls_text_previous_slide-block_1 {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

There is one problem, in example above 'block_1' is views slideshow block, number after '_0' tell that is first slide item and '_2' tell that is third item, so you must change '_2' every time when is number of slide items is changed. For me that code resolve problem because I have only three images in slide and that wasn't ever change.

Maybe someone have better solution or can help fix this problem?

Comment: Smell code, I've never use views slideshow before, but guess [this issue](https://drupal.org/node/990336) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way out is to use css. Hide the control when you don't need it.The particular element can be found by a simple inspection. Hope it helps.

```
display:none;
```

Another alternative is to use the slideshow API to customise the behaviour. You can start [here.](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/views_slideshow/views_slideshow.api.php/7.3)

Comment: I hide 'pause' like that but for control elements (previous, pause, next) I can't find any parent class or id that is related with slide image, control elements are separated...slideshow API probably can help but I have no clue how to do that...

Comment: Oops sorry about that. The API allows you to write your own custom function to control some aspects of the slideshow. Time allowing I might script one for you as a starter. Let me look at the CSS classes and see what they got :-)

Comment: you can see on [this page](http://wizard.whitecircle-design.com/flavia)...thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still looking for it's solution then here it is.
First you need to add **json2** library with json2.js file inside it.
This will give jQuery Cycle Custom Options in your slideshow settings.
There under the Advanced options select **after** and under Advanced option value add following script:

```
var index = options.currSlide;
    $('#prev')[index == 0 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
    $('#next')[index == options.slideCount - 1 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
```

Here prev and next are your ids.
Update Advanced options and you are good to go.